# How to open Google Chrome with RSelenium?

Tags: r, google-chrome, browser, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I am using RSelenium and I want to open and navigate Google Chrome. However, I always get an error when I want to open the browser from R. The following code is used:

```
library("RSelenium")
startServer()
mybrowser <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
mybrowser$open()

[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
 Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
 class: java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

The same code works for Firefox. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even though Google Chrome is installed, there is still something missing that is needed by Selenium. This is the "chromedriver". "chromedriver" can be downloaded [on this website.](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) Currently, [the most recent version is 2.25](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.25/). For instance, if one is using Windows, the file "chromedriver_win32.zip" needs to be downloaded.

When the file is downloaded, extract the file in it, i.e. "chromedriver.exe". Place "chromedriver.exe" where you want it to be. I put it in "User/Documents/R".

In the last step, you need to add the folder where "chromedriver.exe" is located to the system path. A description for adding a folder to the system path can be found [here.](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path)

Now, one can restart *R* and run the code.

Comment: Thank you - the documentation doesn't mention these steps at all!