# RSelenium headless authentication download file

Tags: r, phantomjs

I would like to use this code with a headless browser (e.g. phantomjs or casperjs) and then download the csv file at the end (instead of the native browser's saver popup dialog).

```
library("RSelenium")
startServer()
mybrowser <- remoteDriver(browserName = 'chrome')
mybrowser$open()
mybrowser$navigate("http://steamspy.com/login/")
wxbox <- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/input[@name = 'username']")
wxbox$sendKeysToElement(list("myusername"))
wxbox <- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/input[@name = 'password']")
wxbox$sendKeysToElement(list("mypassword"))
wxbutton <- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/button[@name = 'submit']")
wxbutton$clickElement()
mybrowser$navigate("http://steamspy.com/sale.php?tagid=0&from=2015-04-01&to=2016-04-25&submit=")
wxbutton <- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#ToolTables_tablesales_0")
wxbutton$clickElement()
```

Simply by changing `chrome` with `phantomjs` leads to this following error at opening and navigating the page:

```
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Psidom Windows 10

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540954/how-to-open-google-chrome-with-rselenium

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31124702/rselenium-unknownerror-java-lang-illegalstateexception-with-google-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Install PhantomJS if you haven't done this: Go [Here](http://phantomjs.org/download.html). Download the windows zip file and extract it;

Add the path to **phantoms.exe** which is usually in the *extractedFolder\bin* to the environment variable path by going to Control Panel -> System -> advanced system settings -> environment variables, and add the path to the PATH variable, ignore this if you know how to this already;

Restart your RStudio or R session;

Run the following:

```
library(RSelenium)
pJS <- phantom()
myBrowser <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs")
myBrowser$open()
```

Comment: PhantomJS doesn't see element that Chrome does. I get `Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
   Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
   class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException` at `wxbutton <- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#ToolTables_tablesales_0")`

Comment: By `wxbutton <- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#ToolTables_tablesales_0")`, which element are you trying to find?

Comment: The csv download button, it only appears once one is logged in. PhanthomJS may not save the authentication state before moving into the new page.

Comment: It should normally since it is a browser. Did you replaced the username and password with you login information?

Comment: And also try `mybrowser$setWindowSize(1400, 1000)` before trying to find the element.

Comment: Yes, I replaced them. I find the behavior with phantomjs unconsistent, at some runs I get ` Summary: InvalidElementState
   Detail: An element command could not be completed because the element is in an invalid state (e.g. attempting to click a disabled element).
   class: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException
` at `wxbox$sendKeysToElement`

Comment: `mybrowser$setWindowSize(1400, 1000)` doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Set a `Sys.sleep(10)` between `navigate` and `findElement`. You need to set some time for the browser to load the page. Set `10` accordingly it is the estimated seconds for loading the page.

Comment: It doesn't work with `sys.sleep`. I notice RStudio command line doesn't immediately give the prompt back `>` while executing `navigate`. I assume it's loading the long page at that moment.